# Contact Form PHP not being sent to email

Tags: php

Hello i have a contact form PHP from a theme i purchased. I've been trying to make a customized form with it but with no luck. Tried changing the variables around to work for the one i made myself but it is not being sent to the email i want the information to go to.

This is what i have in my HTML

```
 <form id="" action="application/application.php" method="post" class="validateform" name="send-contact">

<div id="sendmessage">
  Your message has been sent. Thank you!
</div>


                     Youtube Channel Name <br> <input type="text" name="youtubename" placeholder="* Enter Your YouTube Name"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div>

                     First Name <br> <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Enter Your First Name"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div>

                     Last Name <br> <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Enter Your Last Name"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div>

                     Your Paypal Email Address <br> <input type="text" name="paypal" placeholder="* Enter Your Paypal Email"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div>

                     Your YouTube Email Address <br> <input type="text" name="youtubeemail" placeholder="* Enter Your YouTube Email"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div> 

                     Skype <br> <input type="text" name="skype"      ``placeholder="* Enter Your Skype Name"> 
                     <div class="validation"></div>                                      

                       <button class="btn btn-theme margintop10 pull-left" type="submit">Submit Application</button>
                       </form>
```

And for my PHP i have the following;

```
<?php


include 'config.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
$youtubename = stripslashes($_POST['youtubename']);
$firstname = stripslashes($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = stripslashes($_POST['lastname']);
$paypal = stripslashes($_POST['paypal']);
$youtubeemail = trim($_POST['youtubeemail']);
$skype = stripslashes($_POST['skype']);





 $error = '';



 if(!$error)
 {
 $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message
 "From: ".$firstname." <".$youtubename.">\r\n"
."Reply-To: ".$youtubeemail."\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}


}
?>
```

And in my config.php i have

```
<?php
// To
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'Support@XvinityNetwork.com');
?>
```

I'm not very savvy with HTML and i have a member of my staff that does this however has had an emergency issue to attend to this and i need to get this contact form up and running. I do have the default form that came with the theme and it works perfectly so im guessing i've done something wrong here. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: This bit looks like it has the wrong quotes, could cause and issue ``placeholder="

Comment: So what have you done to try to debug this.  There are a number of reasons that `mail()` might not work.  Are you getting errors? Have you properly configured your mail relay?  Can you see the mail in the mail queue on the server?

Comment: hmm the Placeholder is just for the text inside the actual bar. This is what it looks like [link](http://puu.sh/3Y2xQ.png)

@MikeBrant i've changed the "from:" to $first name. I've also switched the youtubeemail 'trim' to 'stripslashes' in the hope that it would fix it. As i've said. The theme comes with a php form and everything it's all identical apart from the $youtubename-$skype i have in there.

Comment: @MrPie That doesn't really answer the question. I was asking what DEBUGGING have you don, not what changes you have made to try to see if something just happens to work.  Have you looked at your error logs to verify there are no errors? Have you looked into the mail queue on the server? Have you simply tried to execute a very simple, hard-coded `mail()` function to see if it works?

Comment: @MikeBrant Sorry i'm not sure how to check the mail queue on the server. I'm using Godaddy.

Answer (score 2):

A notable error is you are missing a comma between `$message` and headers:

```
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message, // Here
 "From: ".$firstname." <".$youtubename.">\r\n"
."Reply-To: ".$youtubeemail."\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Not sure how i missed it. It was definitely in the default PHP. Put it in and uploaded. Still nothing.

Comment: @MrPie, please note that both your `$subject` and `$message` are undefined.  Please have a look at the docs for requirement for subject and message: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Well since i have none of these. Would it be fine to replace them with $firstname and $lastname instead?

edit: I've just replaced them with 

 $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $youtubeemail, $firstname,            $lastname,

Comment: To test your mail functionality, sure.  Or just `mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, 'test subject', 'test message');`

Comment: thanks for the help so far @vinodadhikary I've just used your example to test mail functionality and i'm still not getting anything to the email. The contact form that came with the html theme is set up using the same code (apart from a few changes such as the $youtubeemail) is sending emails without any problem.

Comment: Update: Okay seems like the email was indeed being sent. Logged into Godaddy and checked mail from there. However they are coming up blank. I have been using Outlook to check emails. Is there a reason why it wasn't picking them up?

Comment: @MrPie, that's because your `$message` variable and `$subject` variable are undefined.  But the last email with 'test subject' and 'test message' should not have come up blank.

Comment: i have tried that and have also put in $lastname and $firstname which are defined and yet the emails are still coming up blank. Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1):

You have few syntax errors. A good redactor was solving your problem in a minute.
First of all the "skype" input - it has two quotes in it. Remove it. Second, in the mail function, you adding undefined `$message`, with no operator (such as dot) to random text. if `$message` containing something, place "." after it, and if not, just delete it. And if you meant to add headers, just add comma after the `$message`.

Comment: Hmmph "Skype" has two quotes on it? If you are referring to the '' i think i accidently put that in when pasting the code in here. It's not in the HTML. I have removed $message, thanks.